# How To Display PHP Loop Results Instantly Using JS Script

Tags: php, javascript, loops, output

Here is example of code I'm expecting to print message each second.

```
set_time_limit(60);

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value;

    sleep(5);
}
```

I'm wondering how a JS script should look like to output results of $value during each step in loop instantly without waiting until it stops?

Comment: use `AJAX` and call `PHP` data.

Comment: output buffering might be the best way to go here. (fab beat me to it :) )

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access PHP variables using JavaScript. JavaScript is run inside the browser whereas PHP runs on the server.

You have to use fab's solution and send the current output buffer to the browser with *echo* and [*flush()*](http://php.net/manual/de/function.flush.php). But as soon as you do this, there is no need to use JavaScript anymore, since the text will be displayed anyway.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value;
    flush();

    sleep(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can (and should) do all of the timing stuff for you, it would be much more sensible to output the array as an encoded JSON string that can be printed into your HTML as a javascript variable.

```
<script>
var array = "<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>";
</script>
```

You can then easily use javascript to parse the array, and use the browser to display each message 1 second apart. Once you've converted the array back from a JSON string to an array something like...

```
var clearInterval = setInterval(deliver_message,1000); // Run a function every second

function deliver_message() {
    document.write(array.shift()); //This could be a Jquery append, or similar
    if (array.length == 0)
        clearInterval(loop);
}
```

Your server side processing is there to deliver all the information to the browser, it's client side...javascript...that is there to manipulate how it is displayed.

Answer (score -1):

Why JavaScript?

You can send output at any time before the script finishes with [`flush()`](http://php.net/flush):

```
set_time_limit(60);

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value;
    flush();

    sleep(5);
}
```